# How to make legacy PHP URLs work with Laravel controller?

Tags: laravel, apache, routes, laravel-routing

I am moving a product information page to a Laravel based controller and having issue with preserving the original legacy URLs. The customer wants the product page URLs preserved. Legacy product page URLs come in two forms:

```
1. /12345-product-slug.html
2. /product_info.php?products_id=12345
```

I am getting 404 page from Laravel for the second URL scheme.

Here is what I have done so far.

I am using a combination of Apache's mod_alias, mod_rewrite and Laravel router.

DocumentRoot is `/var/sites/project` and it holds the legacy code which is currently in production.

The new Laravel project resides in `/var/sites/project/laravel`. I want to gradually migrate certain pages (URLs) to the Laravel project. So I have the following in my httpd.conf.

```
Alias /products/ /var/sites/project/laravel/

RewriteRule ^/([0-9]+)-([a-z0-9]+(-[a-z0-9]+)*)\.html$ /products/$1?permalink=$2 [PT]

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} products_id=(\d+)
RewriteRule ^/product_info\.php$ /products/%1? [PT]
```

I have the following route in Laravel's `routes/web.php`

```
Route::get('products/{product}', 'ProductInfoController@index')->name('products');

Route::get('{product}', 'ProductInfoController@index')->where('product', 'product_info\.php\?products_id=([0-9]+)|([0-9]+)-([a-z0-9]+(-[a-z0-9]+)*)\.html');
```

I have the following route binding defined in `RouteServiceProvider.php`

```
public function boot()
    {
        parent::boot();

        Route::bind('product', function ($value) {
            if(!preg_match('/([0-9]+)-([a-z0-9]+(-[a-z0-9]+)*)\.html/', $value, $matches)) {
                preg_match('/product_info\.php\?products_id=([0-9]+)/', $value, $matches);
            }
            return Product::findOrFail($matches[1] ?? $value);
        });
    }
```

I want the same product page to be accessible at the below URLs, but not all of them is working.

- /products/12345 (working)
- /12345-product-slug.html (working)
- /product_info.php?products_id=12345 (NOT WORKING, 404 page)

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: IMHO you can do all only with routes, you can try something like that: `Route::get('{slug}.html',...`  and `Route::get('product_info.php',....`